# Configuring Saxon for MySQL

Tags: mysql, saxon, exist-db

I'm having difficulty getting Saxon configured to use MySQL, in oXygen and in eXist-db.  Here is my attempt in eXist-db xquery.  There are no errors, I do get a connection object (so the fields extracted from my.cnf do appear to work), but no results are returned from `sql:execute()`.  Any suggestions?

```
xquery version "3.1";
declare namespace transform="http://exist-db.org/xquery/transform";

let $xml := <root/>
let $xsl := <xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:file="http://expath.org/ns/file"
    xmlns:wq="https://winequest.com"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:sql="http://saxon.sf.net/sql"
    exclude-result-prefixes="file wq xs map sql"
    version="3.0" expand-text="yes">
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="cnf" select="file:read-text('/etc/my.cnf')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="client" select="$cnf =&gt; replace('^.*\[client\]', '', 's') =&gt; replace('\[[^\]]+\].*$', '', 's')" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="host" select="analyze-string($client, 'host\s+=\s+(.*)')/*:match/*:group/text()" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="database" select="analyze-string($client, 'database\s+=\s+(.*)')/*:match/*:group/text()" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="user" select="analyze-string($client, 'user\s+=\s+(.*)')/*:match/*:group/text()" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="password" select="analyze-string($client, 'password\s+=\s+(.*)')/*:match/*:group/text()" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="connection-map" select="map{{   'database':'jdbc:mysql://'||$host||':3306/'||$database||'?serverTimezone=America/Los_Angeles',   'driver':'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver',   'user':$user,   'password':$password,   'autoCommit':true()}}"/>
        <xsl:variable name="connection" select="sql:connect($connection-map)"/>
        <sql-results>
            <xsl:sequence select="sql:execute($connection, 'SHOW DATABASES')"/>
        </sql-results>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

let $parameters := 
    <parameters>
        <param name="exist:stop-on-error" value="yes"/>
    </parameters>

let $config := 
    <configuration xmlns="http://saxon.sf.net/ns/configuration">
        <xslt>
            <extensionElement namespace="http://saxon.sf.net/sql" factory="net.sf.saxon.option.sql.SQLElementFactory"/>
        </xslt>
    </configuration>

let $results := transform:transform($xml, $xsl, $parameters, $config, ())
return $results
```

Comment: Do use an edition of Saxon that supports the SQL extension? Does your code work with Saxon from oXygen or from the command line without using eXist-db?

Comment: Which version of eXist-db are you using?

Comment: Solution was found, but just to answer all questions: I tested on Saxon 9.9 and 11.4.  The behavior was the same with and without eXist-db.  eXist-db version is 6.0.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of `sql:execute()` says that it returns no results, so it appears to be working as designed. It's designed to enable execution of SQL commands for the sake of their side effects (like `DROP TABLE`).

I'm not sure how the `SHOW DATABASE` command operates at the JDBC level. I guess you would do a call on `Statement.execute()` followed by a call on `Statement.getResultSet()`. Unfortunately I don't think there's anything in Saxon's SQL function library that quite corresponds to that.

Comment: Ah, I did miss something important.  So I needed to use `sql:query()` to return results.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Michael Kay for pointing me in the right direction.  Here is the change that got results to return.  Note, no $config was needed.

```
xquery version "3.1";
declare namespace transform="http://exist-db.org/xquery/transform";

let $xml := <root/>
let $xsl := <xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:file="http://expath.org/ns/file"
    xmlns:wq="https://winequest.com"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:sql="http://saxon.sf.net/sql"
    exclude-result-prefixes="file wq xs map sql"
    version="3.0" expand-text="yes">
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="cnf" select="file:read-text('/etc/my.cnf')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="client" select="$cnf =&gt; replace('^.*\[client\]', '', 's') =&gt; replace('\[[^\]]+\].*$', '', 's')" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="host" select="analyze-string($client, 'host\s+=\s+(.*)')/*:match/*:group/text()" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="database" select="analyze-string($client, 'database\s+=\s+(.*)')/*:match/*:group/text()" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="user" select="analyze-string($client, 'user\s+=\s+(.*)')/*:match/*:group/text()" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="password" select="analyze-string($client, 'password\s+=\s+(.*)')/*:match/*:group/text()" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:variable name="database" select="'jdbc:mysql://'||$host||':3306/'||$database||'?serverTimezone=America/Los_Angeles'"/>
        <xsl:variable name="connection-map" select="map{{   'database':$database,   'driver':'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver',   'user':$user,   'password':$password,   'autoCommit':true()}}"/>
        <xsl:variable name="connection" select="sql:connect($connection-map)"/>
        <sql-results>
            <xsl:for-each select="sql:prepared-query($connection, 'SELECT menu_template_name FROM menu_templates ORDER BY menu_template_name')()">
                <result test="{{?menu_template_name}}"/>
            </xsl:for-each>   
        </sql-results>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

let $parameters := 
    <parameters>
        <param name="exist:stop-on-error" value="yes"/>
    </parameters>

let $results := transform:transform($xml, $xsl, $parameters)
return $results
```